# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на картинку скачивался файл?

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста)) Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на картинку скачивался документ? Я сделала через download НО как его привязать к картинке??

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вывести изображение и обернуть его в ссылку на файл:

```
<a href="ссылка на документ"><img src="ссылка на картинку" border="0"/></a>
```

Comment: Добавьте про ануляцию неистового "квадрата" вокруг картинки border = 0 :)

Comment: @nick_n_a кстати давно уже ничего этого стремного синего бордера не видел)

Answer (score 0):

можешь написать в кнопке такое значение

```
<a href="файл" download=""></a>
```